# TypeScript - generic type inferred as unknown

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a function with a couple generics and rely on generic type inference for resolving them so I can avoid requiring my users to type all of the generic parameters. Below is a contrived example that I hope illustrates my issue:

```js
declare function createFactory<T, R>(build: (params?: T) => T, args: R): R;
```

The following works as expected:

```js
// T=string, R=1
const result = createFactory(() => 'a string', 1);
```

But, when I try to use `params` in the function I pass to `createFactory`, TypeScript no longer seems able to infer the type of `T` and therefore types it as unknown:

```js
// T=unknown, R=1
const result = createFactory((params) => 'a string', 1);
```

I'm not sure why this occurs. It seems like TypeScript wants to infer the type of `T` from `params` when it's present instead of inferring from the return type of the function. The only solution I can think of in this case is to explicitly specify the generic types instead of relying on inference:

```js
// T=string, R=number
const result = createFactory<string, number>((params) => 'a string', 1);
```

However, I am trying to avoid this in my case, as my actual function utilizes several complicated generics, and having my users explicitly define them would be unwieldy.

Is there a way to get this to work with inference and have the `T` type inferred correctly? Or is there a form of partial inference or workaround that would allow users of this function to only have to explicitly define the single generic? I know that TS does not yet support actual [partial type argument inference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26349).

Here is the [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXzDigxADEpMcYBPAHgBUAaeAJQD4AKAI2SwmABc8DgAdYUALYBnAPxD6ASngBeNvCbxYAcylCWCvQG4AUMYD0Z9cqkYYWVFuYtlARmOEQxMhQxVqHDiVVeAByGzsHEOYXBRNzS3plNABrVBwAd1QnV3ciEnJKGgCxGEkpILUw23stKPgYuIsrcJrs1GQJLhAYXM98nz9aFodmds7uzlFxaQrQ4dro2NMm+gALLCl4dJxkfngu+FQsMBBmHgxDnHgS7CgIeHtEbpB0EF6vAt8aIeqHSZKyrMqhEFvVYkA) with these examples.

And here is the [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAixhgAoENYCWuANgDwAqAfHALxzlygzAB2AJgM5zZQEC2BGAQBuwAFBw4Afm74hJCpQlwAXPUYhm7LgEEoUXIlK4WiJZJnllahk1ac4AZWAxjp89PrX1d7XABKwLhsECzEiM6uJmbKlt62mvZcALK4YG6IADRw0R5xkjYaWg6BwaHhqenR2bmxXgU+iX4AFAB07fgA5hxq0QDaALoAlLTUAK4sANYsEADuLHUMAD5wE2zAAGYELMBs8UVJcBAARgBWwADGMHUYWHiEJADyZ5euVN4T03MsANxiYkgUNxeAIhKJaHAWGNiMQ4Cs1pttrs4XAODBeCxOiioXxjsAoCjjhAIMQgiwURxELiSYSCJ1tjA-gDkKhbjg5ERiM9zldSNzXuQWQc-CceTBqHQAN7KPoAaWAiEFQO2cEmCogGzg-KuSuAAykajZ93kZG1MF1coVuoGlD+AF8maBILAEEKAEJjAjENiPMBCUIcRQQ6WSDjAACOY1YF2AahxeKgf0kYHwuD4PXQmHZDzIVHtTMBqHIBkEHAAkiwwGM3tli7hSxK4CG4H064I4Cq1YgNfQSzAOAM1M0RjRqMbOYp8-8ndB4IW4AAxXBXaCICtokwx0jKciZHd9jjc4UONv9itVmtNu2UPeSADCUCCzDYt7gZb3jebx093rUpA9XpsPcaZcL4J6UM0yjJqm6YGqq6qagB3rAemx5cF2PZGhyCjvJIeGeFhOb-j+QEwRwHj4YaWbjjhN7KCO1AMAAZHASGkQY6ZJsef4AHLALMuoQVBcAphxGZ8QJLKvgxi7LjAq7rjAm7ABQcAsRJuq1ge3LZA+T67NkZa2sookgUOpnplRdzYbmlAyUuK5QGuLAbiwW67r29b9jpcB6bgz6GcZkgXI+-mxr5oXPmhASXNAbAZDU7jCTIzSimoNG2TJPAQAIYakH5z4UaokLAKIiZiHaalNjKp4duSGGaqeh5nIOcDDqMsmOc5rlbsJTXcq2fYDNF7WjnVGz4nAACqnjMdNxW7n12lnK+96RQZwllsoxkOtO4CznAGwTFcBChHAIX6Q58lOdukiLXdB7ntWoFNCej2VtWFDZJK16vu+ygFRtQmSOsWw7GozaSN+gFDhAfqnS5ahsb6-ouYoMnkFxkjol5HBwU1T39lj53rXBqVnDYWVQDlBB5YDbBBXAdqvhZeNWdmJqKHuQxqFdCkuUpbkqR5BMff2unrS+b7UM2pLwGGkbRqgdAAIxMsFAbwND3oQs02vsWZmbWURVAyZD52a0c8MBsGwmhhGUZC2oCuOzGADUburXhrNqPrKEcF7u3CQA9MHORXGMJAdnwYCknwrBKaj2TfvAxAEMcBhOQAtGA1PCAQ6xsHA6xYMk+KdKgMzwLgwj1sQuDHKSdUIAAFrTIn14gnTU2sKgh8Hj4wGMUDkiXYBl1AFfNKDSKtPrqXWy5QzZKzyckf72Tx5PwB3mMaI0wAXviQzq3hg-D6PiI7HPJEL6jHAn8oQeSOfI-Vfh+uvpVuBcNE9r-POKaYYCRSg7GwZ26JtidB+JCNM4U0QYixEHUO6h26FiLhcaAj4rjhByFwSUYCIGIOyCwOBRCoFMzEBdMKfMnLNAIfrIcMl6GELgAAchVmwkhZD2GOGYGAFurA2FMxGHaIY-wUEMHbp8GY8wqHrVoYgFhjC2oENZiIjqLCC5qA4Vw2B8cdF8KwIIlgwixEiIkWHcgbcuCzGgJMAOcAU4dl-nANOMAYBNwuGMXE+IOA5VQBsaAqxgEcHkZdOSq5lEkSHGosiTMkYkRRgjQMQD8R2U0QQ7R7DOHcIMbw-hJizGiKGEAA) with my actual, real-world case, which is a little more complex than the contrived example.

Comment: You don't use `params` in any of your examples, and in all cases it has an implicit type of `unknown`. How would you expect `params` to be used?

Comment: I think that in the first case TS infers T from the return value, because it's the only value available. In the second case it infers T from the `params` that is unknown. You can manually add `string|undefined` type to the `params` in the second example, that way TS will understand your intention. Or in other words: how TS should know if `params` is supposed to be `string|undefined` and not `string|number|undefined` for example?

Comment: @AlexWayne In my real-world case, I will be merging the params onto the returned object, which I think will further mess up the ability of TS to infer the type .

Comment: @ŁukaszZaroda It seems odd that TS tries to infer from `params` instead of the return value since `params` can be anything unless explicitly typed. You're right that manually typing the params does work, just something I wanted to avoid.

Comment: Well why does `params` need to be generic? The whole issue you are having revolves around the type of `params`, so how you type that and use that is extremely relevant.

Comment: @stephen.hanson Maybe think about it this way: TS has two informations that it can use for inference. `T` has to be figured out from the return value type, and the params type. If there are no params, situation is clear. But if there are params, then what they can be? How TS could know that? As far as it knows, everything is possible here, so it defaults to `unknown`.

Comment: @AlexWayne that makes sense, thank you. It does need to be generic. I've updated my post and added a TS Playground link that shows with my real-world use instead of the contrived example. At the end of the day, my goal is to have a `createFactory` function that is easy for a user to use. Till now, I've been expecting the user to be able to rely completely on inference, and I'm not super happy with the API if they have to explicitly type `params`.

Comment: What do you _expect_ to be the type of `params` in `createFactory({ build: ({ params }) => ({ id: '1', name: 'Stephen' }) })` then?

Comment: Params will always be a `DeepPartial<T>`, where `T` is the return type of the build function. It seems like this is a circular relationship, however. Maybe what I'm really needing (but which doesn't exist) is partial type inference, so I can specify the type of T explicitly. For reference, I'm working on a rewrite of this [library and feature](https://github.com/thoughtbot/fishery#use-params-to-access-passed-in-properties) to go from a class-based to function-based implementation.

Comment: If you explicitly type the callback in the contrived example it works as expected: `createFactory((params?: string) => 'string', 1);` gives T=string and R=1.